# Redirecting HTTP traffic to HTTPS in EC2 hosted web server using cloudfront

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, .htaccess, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

**Current Scenario**

I am hosting a wordpress website on a `ECS` instance which runs wordpress in a docker container

My wordpress is working fine but i want to change `HTTP` to `HTTPS`

**What i dont want to use**

1) ELB

2) Anything cost ineffective

**What i tried**

I tried using cloud front and setting `ec2-52-64-xxx-xxx.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com` as `origin domain` and `origin id`

I also set it to `redirect HTTP to HTTPS`

**Current CloudFront behaviour**

What happens is when i goto the cloudfront link it redirects me to `ec2-52-64-xxx-xxx.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com` `(HTTP)` instead of using the cloudfront link

**Desired CloudFront behaviour**

It should use the `HTTPS` cloudfront URL to use my wordpress website by redirecting any traffic from my origin from `HTTP` to `HTTPS`

**Current Server configs**

1) I don't have any `SSL/TLS` certificate installed in my `ECS` instance

2) My `.htaccess` file has default values (not sure if i even should update it or cloudfront will work without any changes to `.htaccess`)

3) Wordpress is not installed so the database does not have any values which might be causing a redirect ( I deleted the database to test if that might be causing the inconsistency)

I am really new to AWS,There might be a better way to achieve `HTTP` to `HTTPS` redirect i think any sugggestions/help is highly appreciated thanks :)

Comment: From [AWS Cloudfront redirecting to S3 bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45047048/174777): _S3 updates the DNS for the global REST endpoint hierarchy *.s3.amazonaws.com with a record sending requests to the right region for the bucket within a short time after bucket creation, and CloudFront appears rely on this for sending the requests to the right place. Before that initial update is complete, S3 will return a redirect and CloudFront returns that redirect to the browser._ Therefore, just wait a while (a few hours?) and it will start working as you expect.

Comment: S3 ? but my origin is an ec2 instance Public DNS ... also will i have to update the `.htaccess` file to allow URL rewrites ? ( Also i waited the entire night around 6 hours) did not work out for me :((

Comment: Oops, my bad! If you have waited 6 hours, things should have updated. This sounds like a case for contacting AWS Support. (Yes, you'll need to subscribe, but the assistance you can get from AWS Support will save you a lot of time figuring this out.)