# AWS Cloudfront can't access S3 files deployed with CodeBuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-codebuild

I'm working on getting a static website deployed with AWS Codebuild, hosted in an S3 bucket, and accessed via Cloudfront. Everything seems to work except from accessing from Cloudfront. From Cloudfront, I can access files that I manually upload, and using the bucket URL, I can access all the files. Looking through the individual file settings/permissions, they all look to be the same, regardless of whether they were manually uploaded, or deployed via Codebuild. I've tried invalidating the Cloudfront cache, and re-deployed via Codebuild several times.

---

Additional Information:

I provided the S3 bucket as an origin when setting up the Cloudfront distribution.

Accessing via Cloudfront gives the following error:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>0211CBE618946F</RequestId>
<HostId>
7sRZhaJS4x2W7Iaeo4y8KAjvsOJcNWh3PxCdgnhXPE22oyp1RxZhwpjrqbsWapsUSaqBK+jqE=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

What else should I check?

Comment: What error code or message do you get when accessing via CloudFront? And how did you provide CloudFront with access to your S3 bucket?

Comment: @jarmod Check the edits to the question

Comment: How recently did you deploy it? Unless you're using US East (N. Virginia) as your region it'll take a bit of time for the DNS records to be created and propagate for new created S3 buckets - good explanation [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58423033/2064596).

Comment: @OscarSchafer Thanks! It's been deploy since before I tested with a manually uploaded file (which worked fine).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

For some reason, adding a default root object fixed the issue.

FWIW, I initially changed the value to `dist/index.html`, which allowed me to access the deployed bucket contents via the Cloudfront URL, but required the `index.html` suffix. Once I changed it to `index.html`, everything worked fine.