# AWS Subdomain with a ReactJS App using route53

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I'm really lost,

I have one ReactJS app on aws :

- Name : Test APP 1
- Domain management : https://hello-42test.io

I would like to have another ReactJS app "Test APP 2", totaly independent, but under a subdomain
https://back.hello-42test.io

I found were I can add sub domain under domain management but its only for the app "Test App 1"
Even with reading the doc I dont get how to do that

Answer (score 0):

If you have already setup the domain using Route53 then you can publish the new website to a S3 bucket and use CloudFront to redirect the subdomain to the bucket.

[AWS CloudFront redirecting to S3 bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38735306/aws-cloudfront-redirecting-to-s3-bucket)